# Error in declaring array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Working through an intro JS coursera course. I'm making a simple color guessing game. I've inserted a few alerts at the beginning for troubleshooting, but I can't get this program to get reach the alert("test1"); line in my playGame, which is loading immediately through the body element. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I seem to be declaring it just fine...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="playGame()">
<p>Welcome to my color guessing game</p>
<script language = "JavaScript">
function inArray(needle, haystack){
    for (var i = 0; i <haystack.length(); i++){
        if (needle === haystack[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function changeBackground(color){
    document.body.style.background = color;
}
function playGame(){
    var correct = false; 
    alert("Correct status is: " + correct);
    var colorArray = ["cyan", "gold", "green", "gray", "magenta", "blue", "red", "orange", "yellow", "white"];
    alert("test1");
    for (var i = 0; i < colorArray.length(); i++){
        alert("for " + i + " the color is " + colorArray[i]);
    }
    colorArray = colorArray.sort();
    alert("answer index is " + answerIndex);
    alert("color array length is " + colorArray.length());
    var answerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length());
    alert("the resulting color from the color array is: " + answerColor);
    var answerColor = colorArray[answerIndex];
    alert("The correct color is " + answerColor);
    var answerList = colorArray.join(", ");
    var guessCount = 0;
    while(!correct){
        var colorGuess = prompt("Welcome to my guessing game! The colors available for your choosing are: " + "\n\n" + answerList + "\n\n" + "Which color am I thinking of?");
        guessCount++;
        if (!inArray(colorGuess, colorArray)){
            alert("Your guess wasn't one of the selections that was available or I otherwise don't recognize it." + "\n\n" + "Please try again!");
        }
        else{
            if (colorArray.indexOf(colorGuess)<color.indexOf(answerColor)){
                alert("Your guess was alphabetically before the correct color! Try again.");

            }
            else if (colorARray.indexOf(colorguess)>color.indexOf(answerColor)){
                alert("Your guess was alphabetically after the correct color! Try again.");
            }
            else{
                alert("Your guess is correct!");
                correct = true;
                changeBackground(answerColor);
            }
        }
    }
    alert("Great job!" + "\n\n" + "You took " + guessCount + " guesses to get the correct answer!");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also please check if you are getting any error in console

Comment: .length() => .length

Comment: *"...can't...reach the `alert("test1");` line"*  Are you saying it *does* display the alert just before the `var colorArray =...` line, but not the one after?

Comment: you should see the console and check the error. IF you are not able to solve edit the question so that we can have clear view of your problem.

Comment: @AnandSingh You're right :) -- Been a while since I've come back to coding and SO.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your code.

```
alert("answer index is " + answerIndex);
            alert("color array length is " + colorArray.length());
            var answerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length());
            alert("the resulting color from the color array is: " + answerColor);
            var answerColor = colorArray[answerIndex];
            alert("The correct color is " + answerColor);
```

Here you're trying to alert the variable `answerIndex`, before you declare it.

Comment: This is more like a comment to me.

Comment: This would just alert `undefined`,  it wouldn't stop the function from continuing.

Answer (score 0):

In JS `length` is a property which returns the number of elements in an array. [MDN Array Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

In `colorArray.length()` replace `length()` by `length`.

Comment: Would someone please tell me what's wrong in my answer and why is it downvoted?